# wp_query crashes when I make an ajax call

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

I am developing a web app with Wordpress. I try to make ajax calls but wp_query crashes and gives me a 500 error while everything works when I make a classic call.

Unable to get error message even with try / catch.

Here is the call of wp-load.php in my functions.php file:

```
require_once(ABSPATH.'wp-load.php');
```

My AJAX call

```
/* Display services in ajax */
function get_services(oasis_id) {
    service_type = "Service";
    url = jQuery('#etape-question-2').attr('action-datas');
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'post',
        data: {oasis_id : oasis_id,service_type:service_type,action: 'get_services_ajax'},
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(context) {    
            var data = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(context));
            data = data.context;
            console.log(data.services);
            if(data.reponse === 'ok') {
                console.log("ok");
            } else {}
        },
        error: function(json) {
            console.log(json);
            console.log('erreur');
        }
    
    });
}
```

My php function

```
/* ---- Redirections pour les calls ajax ---*/
if(isset($_POST['action'])){
    if ($_POST['action'] == "get_services_ajax") {; get_services_ajax(htmlspecialchars($_POST['oasis_id'],ENT_QUOTES),htmlspecialchars($_POST['service_type'],ENT_QUOTES)); }
}

/* Charge les services ou produits ou abonnements d'un oasis */
function get_services_ajax($oasis_id,$service_type){
    
    $services = array();
    $args = array( 
        'post_type' => 'service',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'post_status'    => 'publish',
    );

    $the_query = new WP_Query($args);
   
    if($the_query->have_posts()): 
        while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : 
            $the_query->the_post(); 
                
                $this_service = array();
                $this_service['id'] = get_the_ID();
                $this_service['nom'] = get_field('nom',get_the_ID());
                $this_service['type_de_service'] = get_field('type_de_service',get_the_ID());
                $this_service['oasis'] = get_field_object('oasis',get_the_ID());
                $this_service['therapeutes'] = get_field_object('therapeutes',get_the_ID());
                $this_service['categories'] = get_field('categories',get_the_ID());
                $this_service['tranche'] = get_field('tranche',get_the_ID());
                $this_service['details'] = get_field('details',get_the_ID());
                
                $services[] = $this_service;
        endwhile;
        wp_reset_postdata(); 

        $context = array();
        $context['services'] = $services;
        $context['reponse'] = "ok";
        echo json_encode(['context' =>  $context]);
    endif;
    echo json_encode(['context' =>  'terminé']);
}
```

I have absolutely no ideas, I have done other projects and I never had this problem. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: _"and gives me a 500 error"_ - then go and check what the error log has to say about that.

Comment: Btw., this `if ($_POST['action'] == "get_services_ajax")` is not the proper way to handle AJAX in WordPress. https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins

Comment: @CBroe I will watch, thank you. ok but i don't think that's the problem

Comment: There's a lot fundamentally wrong with your Ajax with respect to using it in WordPress. Follow @CBroe s advice and update your question or you'll just solve all of your problems by doing what he's saying

Comment: It is really easy to make a [custom REST endpoint](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/adding-custom-endpoints/), too. It is a first-class citizen in WordPress, you get security, JSON-encoding, filtering and bunch of other things for free.

Comment: thank you for the informations. I was able to access the logs and the error and the following: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'WP_Query' not found. While as a reminder it works fine without AJAX.